# Android 非同期で複数の処理

Tags: android, java, 非同期

【やりたいこと】
Android にて非同期で複数の処理をしようと考えています。
処理 A, B, C... があり、全ての処理が終わったところで UI側にreceiver.sendしたいです。

【やってみたこと】
Activityから X_IntentServiceを呼び、
そこから A_IntentService, B_IntentService　というように複数の処理を行い、
全て終わったところで X_IntentServiceから `receiver.send()` しようとしたら
A,Bなど各IntentServiceにて receiver.send()した時に以下のExceptionになってしまいます。

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {656e5a68} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

そもそも`IntentService`から `IntentService` は呼べない仕組みなのでしょうか？
A_IntentServiceから receiver.send() した時には X_IntentService の処理がすでに終わってる、ということでしょうか。
また、こう言ったケースのベストプラクティスはありますか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ 質問内容から類推できそうな気もしますが、特定のプログラミング言語を想定していらっしゃるのであれば、そのことをタグまたは本文へ追記してくださるとより文脈が分かりやすくなるかと思います。特に何か使いたいライブラリ等あるのならそれを書いておくと回答しやすいです。自分の質問は質問の下の「編集」からご自由に追記できますので、お試しください。

Comment: こんにちは！私は外国人ですが日本語を勉強している。
user3752013の問題はnon-UIThreadでGUIの方法(メソッド)を使います。non-UIThreadでGUIの方法(メソッド)を使ったら、このExceptionを表示することです。

Comment: Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() { 
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            // ここにG‌​UIの方法を呼び出しください。
        } 
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

通常のJavaのthread(ワーカースレッド)を使用し、join(待ち合わせ)後に処理を開始すればよいと思います。
前の方が記述されておりますが、GUIでないスレッド(メインスレッド)から画面を操作するとアプリケーションが異常終了するので、画面を操作する処理の場合はHandlerを使用する必要があります。

注意点として、Activityでthreadを起動した場合、画面遷移(onPouse or onDestroy)の動作でthreadが動作停止してしまいます。
上記は、Activityではなく、Serviceからthreadを起動させ、バックグランドで常駐させる事で回避が可能です。この辺りはアプリの実装に依存します。

簡単に纏めると、AndroidのServiceは画面遷移を複数挟んでも継続して欲しい処理に対して使用し、その中で並列で走らせたい処理があった場合は、thread等の非同期処理を使用する。が、実装としてシンプルではないでしょうか。

質問の内容の処理なら、サービスを複数起動する必要はないと思います。

Comment: threadに待ち合わせの機能があったんですね！Androidのバックグラウンド処理はIntentServiceを使うべきなんてのを見たのでthreadは考えてませんでした。

Answer (score -1):

別スレッドからUIスレッドへの橋渡しとなるHandlerを使用

```
    Handler handler= new Handler();

 public void onClickButton(View v) {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
  // マルチスレッドにしたい処理 ここから

  final String result = getMessage(); // 何かの処理
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      msgView.setText(result); // 画面に描画する処理
    }
  });

  // マルチスレッドにしたい処理 ここまで
}
```

}).start();
}